# How to manage NULL strings or dates in sql queries (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 11.1
 With the below sql query, where $1 and $2 are strings and $3 is a timestamp, how can the below query be rewritten so that a null value in $3 allows for every date to be selected (not just null dates).

```
   SELECT lastname, firstname, birthdate FROM patients 
           WHERE UPPER(lastname) LIKE UPPER($1)||'%' and UPPER(firstname) LIKE UPPER($2)||'%' AND birthdate::date = $3::date
        UNION
        SELECT lastname, firstname, birthdate FROM appointment_book 
           WHERE UPPER(lastname) LIKE UPPER($1)||'%' and UPPER(firstname) LIKE UPPER($2)||'$' and birthdate::date = $3::date
```

That is, if $3 is null, then this should reduce to:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, birthdate FROM patients 
               WHERE UPPER(lastname) LIKE UPPER($1)||'%' and UPPER(firstname) LIKE UPPER($2)||'%' 
            UNION
            SELECT lastname, firstname, birthdate FROM appointment_book 
               WHERE UPPER(lastname) LIKE UPPER($1)||'%' and UPPER(firstname) LIKE UPPER($2)||'$'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but I think you can handle that with a `CASE` expression

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, birthdate FROM patients p
  WHERE UPPER(p.lastname) LIKE UPPER($1)||'%'
  AND   UPPER(p.firstname) LIKE UPPER($2)||'%'
  AND   (CASE WHEN $3 IS NULL THEN TRUE
         ELSE                      p.birthdate::date = $3::date
         END)
UNION
SELECT lastname, firstname, birthdate FROM appointment_book ab
  WHERE UPPER(ab.lastname) LIKE UPPER($1)||'%'
  AND   UPPER(ab.firstname) LIKE UPPER($2)||'%'
  AND   (CASE WHEN $3 IS NULL THEN TRUE
         ELSE                      ab.birthdate::date = $3::date
         END);
```